# How to integrate Shoutcast MediaStreamSource in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, shoutcast

I downloaded **"Shoutcast MediaStreamSource"** from **http://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/** and ran the sample project with an Icecast stream. It worked perfectly. I just don't know how to integrate this with my Windows Phone project. Should I add the dll files from the bin folder or the projects as a reference?

I tried both but it is giving error. Also, how can I pass the URL to the Audio Playback agent.